# "No" as a word-replacer for "one"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nouns

How can I always use "one" to replace a noun? For example:

```
 - How many items do you have?
 - Fives *ones*.
```

Or

```
 - Are there many chinese there?

 - Yes, there're many *of them*
 or - Yes, I see many *of them* everyday
 or - Yes, I see *ones* everyday
```

Can I always use "no" in this cases?

I know that in some cases "one(s)" can be omitted, but not always.

Are these correct?

```
 - Are there many chinese there?
 - Hai, mainichi takusan NO ga iru
 - Hai, mainichi takusan NO wo miru
```

Comment: In some of those cases, you can use some of the many Counters from japanese language. Try read [this](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/numbers).

Comment: I agree with @CrisCM; just use the counter.  Also, you wouldn't say `takusan NO ga iru`, you would just say `takusan iru`.

Comment: @istrasci he said in some cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not. What you have in mind of "no" as "one" is actually a word that means "one(s) who/which", so does not go well with numbers and quantifiers.

> 赤いの *akai no* = one which is red = red one
>   腐ったの *kusatta no* = one which has rotten = rotten one
>   昨日湖で釣ったの *kinou mizuumi de tsutta no* = one which (I) caught in the lake yesterday
>   5の *go no* = one which is five ≠ five ones

Instead, you have to use:

- "[number] one(s)" → *[number]+[appropriate counter]*
  5人 *go-nin* "five (of people)", 2個 *ni-ko* "two (of small items)", 4本 *yon-hon* "four (of long items)"...
- "some (a few)" → *nan-[appropriate counter]-ka*
  何人か *nan-nin-ka*, 何個か *nan-ko-ka*, 何本か *nan-bon-ka*...
- "some (a lot)" → *nan-[appropriate counter]-mo*
  何人も *nan-nin-mo*, 何個も *nan-ko-mo*, 何本も *nan-bon-mo*...
- "many, few, a couple of..." → generally conveyed through adverbs
  たくさん *takusan*, 少し *sukoshi*, 二三 *ni-san*...

In Japanese, numeral expressions usually stand as adverbs unless you mean "**the** five ones" etc., thus you shouldn't put any particle.

> go-nin iru
>   *go-nin ga iru

Therefore,

```
- How many items do you have?
- Fives *ones*.
```

> 5個 *go-ko*

```
- Are there many chinese there?
- Yes, there're many *of them*
```

> はい、たくさんいます *hai, takusan imasu*
>   はい、何人もいます *hai, nannin mo imasu*

**PS**

> はい、毎日たくさん見ます *hai, mainichi takusan mimasu*

is OK, but you can't say 毎日たくさんいます, unless there spawns many new Chinese everyday.

Comment: rather "hai, mainichi takusan **wo** mimasu", right?

Comment: "hai, nannin mo **wo** imasu" the same

Comment: @Kommi No, neither you can. "Takusan" is an adverb, not a noun, as I said. "Nannin mo wo imasu" doesn't make sense, first `imasu` is an intransitive, second `mo` consumes `ga` and `wo`.

Comment: `second mo consumes ga and wo.`  Most of the time (and in this case), but not always.